# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm new to PHP, and i'm making a forum. all the files work except one file, add_topic.php.

It gives me an error saying:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS in /home/a3885465/public_html/add_topic.php on line 25

I know it is probably on the lines:

```
}
else{
    echo "ERROR";
}
mysql_close();
```

but the whole code is below just in case.

If you have any idea, it would be really appreciated, thanks!

---

The Code for add_topic.php

```
$host=""host"";
$username="username";
$password="password";
$db_name ="database_name";
$tbl_name="forum_question";// Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// get data that sent from form
$topic=  $_POST['topic'];
$detail= $_POST['detail'];
$name=   $_POST['name'];
$email=  $_POST['email'];

$datetime=date("d/m/y h:i:s");//create date time

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(topic, detail, name, email, datetime)VALUES('$topic',
    '$detail', '$name', '$email', '$datetime')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result){
    echo "Successful<BR>";
    echo "<a href=main_forum.php>View your topic</a>";
else{
    echo "ERROR";
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: There is no occurrence of "class" in the code you show. Please show the exact line where the error occurs in, and the three before and after that

Comment: I wanted to make your code more readable until I saw all the mark-up between it. Please remove all this HTML Mark-up and format your code accordingly

Comment: @DrColossos - I think you misunderstand the question...this is syntax highlighting markup (as you'd see on this page), or supposed to be, not actual running code.

Comment: Can you use "Code Sample" button please...

Comment: @Nick, OK now I see, I thought that this is just a copy&paste from some editor that adds its own styles and so since I was wondering about the CSS parts at the beginning, nevermind.

Comment: Sorry, I saved it as a .rtf file, when I made it in textedit on mac but styling options were retained when changed it to php. I've fixed it now and have got text wrangler, which is far better! Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Plus:
you "double quotet Host.

```
$host=""host""; // Host name
```

replace it with

```
$host="host"; // Host name
```

But seriously: you should probably get yourself a decent IDE!

Comment: I think again the point of the question was missed...this was code someone posted on a forum, like an SO question that he's highlighting...it's not the actual issue, and likely not their code either.

Answer (score 1):

You have an unescaped `<?php` on line 25:

```
<p class="p1"><span class="s1"></span><?php<span class="s2"><br>
```

It should be:

```
<p class="p1"><span class="s1"></span>&lt;?php<span class="s2"><br>
```

Comment: It actually IS escpaed but only in the very wrong place. 7th line from the bottom.

Comment: @DrColossos - I don't think so...he said he's designing a forum, I take that to mean this is *supposed* to be syntax highlighted code output, that's why all the spans are in there.

Answer (score 1):

Three years later here I come:

Your parser is probably complaining about the quadruple quotes around `""host""` on the 1st line. Also

```
echo "<a href=main_forum.php>View your topic</a>";
```

should be

```
echo "<a href=\"main_forum.php\">View your topic</a>";
```

Finally the code is full of opportunities for SQL injection. Shield your input before putting it in a query. There are all sorts of clever tricks to do that, like  [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) and tons of blog posts devoted to the subject.

I personally find that using [`base64`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.phpv) on the input, and decoding it whenever I need to process it works best, if you don't mind the extra space.